# Why do negative numbers often need parentheses to obtain the expected result when squaring?

Tags: python, c, ruby, r, operator-precedence

Does someone know the reason why negative numbers need parentheses to be squared the way one might expect in several programming languages but not in C (or perhaps others)?

Here's an example in R:

```
> -5^2
[1] -25
> # now let's use parentheses
> (-5)^2
[1] 25
```

The same thing happens in Python:

```
>>> -5**2
-25
>>> (-5)**2
25
```

Just for fun, let's also try this in Ruby (used http://repl.it/ as the interpreter):

```
 > 5**2
=> 25
 > -5**2
=> -25
 > (-5)**2
=> 25
```

However, if we implement this short program in C, then negative numbers do not require parentheses to be squared correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int number, product;
  printf("\nEnter the number you want squared: ");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  product = number * number;
  printf("Squared number: %d \n", product);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output from the C program:

```
Enter the number you want squared: 5
Squared number: 25
```

Next, I'll use a negative number:

```
Enter the number you want squared: -5
Squared number: 25
```

If someone knows the story behind this, I'd love to know.

Comment: If you use the same process for squaring in C in the other languages you'll get the same result

Comment: I don't use C, but aren't you doing an R equivalent of, say, `n <- -5; n^2`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto It looks like that's not the case but I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you write the equivalent of your C program in the other languages, you'll see the same result. If C had an exponentiation operator, the C equivalent of the other programs you show would also give the same result. The difference you observe is due to you writing two different programs, not due to different languages behaving differently in this regard.

Comment: You don't need parentheses to get the square correctly. With or without parentheses, you will get the square correctly.

Comment: The confusion may come from the fact that some software ([Excel](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/tutorials/spreadsheet-addiction/#excel)) uses a higher precedence for the unary negation.

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes. I don't know if this is as obvious as some make it sound.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It states as if C behaves differently, which is not correct. It assumes a false premise. Also, it states as if all the programming languages are doing incorrect calculation. They are not. On top of that, how can `-5^2` be interpreted as `-(5^2)` when the `-5` is given as a single variable `number`? Is the OP expecting something like `num = -`, `ber = 5`, to which the precedence applies like `num(ber^2)`?

Comment: @sawa if you don't understand what is happening then it may appear that way. There are plenty of well upvoted questions where the OP does not get an important detail.

Comment: @sawa also as Vincent pointed out Excel actually behaves the way the OP expects. I just tested it myself so this may not be as wacky a misunderstanding as many of you think. The OP may want to add that example to demonstrate that it is not as simple as it may first seem.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I haven't questioned that part of the OP's question. The problem with the OP's question lies in the points that I wrote above.

Comment: I will be deleting my account as a result of being attacked for asking a question.

Comment: @Tyler Please do so if you think so.

Comment: @Tyler I would encourage you to not delete your account b/c of your experience on this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first examples(*Python, Ruby, R*) the exponential operator has higher [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), we can see that is the case for Python from [Python Operator Precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html), Ruby from [Ruby Operator Precedence](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence) and R from [Operator Syntax and Precedence](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html). So the exponential operator will be applied before the unary minus will.

It is worth it to note that as *Vincent Zoonekynd* points out *Excel* actually behaves the way the OP expects in this case and so depending on your background the problem may actually not be as obvious as a lot of the comments purport.

The misunderstanding here appears to be that you expect the `-` to be part of the number, which it is not. The `-` is actually an operator which is applied to the number just like exponentiation.

In *C* you are entering a negative number and therefore there is no operator precedence to deal with. For reference here is C [operator precedence table](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html).

So you are comparing two different things here, if you did something in let's say Python you would see a similar result:

```
>>> x = -5
>>> x**2
25
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you write [image] on your math homework. This means [image], not [image]. It's the same in R, Python, and Ruby. When you write `-5**2`, that means `-(5**2)`, not `(-5)**2`. The exponentiation operator has a higher precedence than the negation.

On the other hand, when you do

```
product = number * number;
```

with a negative `number`, this multiplies the negative number by itself. The negation occurs before the squaring instead of afterward. If you did the same thing in any of the other languages you tried, you would get the same result.